# How to test crypto.subtle in an edge runtime using NodeJS / Jest / VS Code?

Tags: next.js, cryptography

So there have been other questions on here that ask how to test crypto in Jest Unit tests.  But they fail to address the subtlety of testing code that runs in the edge runtime.  As you know any test that wires up "crypto" leverages the NodeJS crypto runtime.  That is not a runtime that is available in the edge runtime environment (aka Next JS middleware contexts)

crypto is simply globally available in an edge environment albeit a very stripped down crypto, which for the most part provides crypto.subtle to do basic things like sign, verify, encrypt and decrypt.

THAT is what I would like to know the answer to, how do you set up a Jest unit test in a NEXT JS 14 typescript project that can actually test functions that implement lines of code such as:

`const key = crypto.subtle.importKey("pkcs8", keyBuf, algo, true, ["sign", "verify"]);` 
Without throwing an error such as: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'importKey')

Unit test would run with no additional configuration and leverage the default edge environment crypto functions without needing to do a Node JS runtime import of "crypto"

Comment: I think you are confusing Node's crypto module with the [SubteCrypto api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto) available in the Javascript engines of most(all) modern browsers. However, Node makes the SubtleCrypto api available within its much larger crypto module since it was not otherwise using the [crypto.subtle](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptosubtle) namespace.